# Dynamic row width compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I need to create a searchbar that looks like this (strictly compose):
[image: Without Text]

[image: With Text]

Now i managed to get the one without text working, but i cannot get the cancel text to show up without bugs.

For example when using constraint row and some paddings i get effect like this
[image: Bug]

link to the working code:

https://gist.github.com/piotrsedlak/d71da26299946ef6fc5125042e04a154

I also tried working with animateContentSize but that didnt really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be easily achieved using `weight` modifier. Conditionally adjust the weights and you'll get the desired effect. Here's a snippet for the same:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DynamicToolbar() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val fieldWeight = if (text.text.isNotBlank()) 0.8f else 1f
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Search, null, tint = Color.DarkGray) },
            trailingIcon = {
                if (text.text.isNotBlank()) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.Close,
                        null,
                        tint = Color.LightGray,
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable { text = text.copy("") }
                    )
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(fieldWeight)
                .alignBy(FirstBaseline)
        )
        if (text.text.isNotBlank()) {
            TextButton(
                onClick = { },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1 - fieldWeight)
                    .alignBy(FirstBaseline)
            ) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Compose `1.0.0-alpha11`

PS: I fixed the baseline alignment problem as well [(credits)](https://github.com/vinaygaba/Learn-Jetpack-Compose-By-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetpackcompose/layout/ViewLayoutConfigurationsActivity.kt#L317). Hope that helps.

Comment: Solution is great, but as you can see in the screenshots, there cant be any "active" color when typing in text, i tried using your solution and setting activeColor to transparent, but then i lose the border and the indicator, do You maybe have a solution for that?

Comment: I thought the focus of this question was handling dynamic width for `Row` component. If you want to customise colors as well, I believe you should have a customised version of `BasicTextField`. I will try to put a solution for that later but that would be irrelevant to the title of this question.

Comment: Well in the gist link you can see that i put basictextfield inside the row, and it doesnt behave correctly (screenshots)

Comment: AFAIK, it's quite difficult to modify existing TextField APIs to build the above shown `TextField`. You can always copy paste internal classes/functions and modify the way you want but it'll impose a burden of maintaining that code as most of the `TextField` APIs are still `experimental`. I think `CoreTextField` function's `decorationBox` parameter will help you adjust border color and `cursorColor` is also there to tweak around.